# How to display HTML content in J2ME?

Tags: html, java-me, midlet, nokia-s40

I am developing a MIDlet for a Nokia (series 40). I want to display an HTML content. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

I've been trying to find this out myself.  I've found a 2 midlet ereader that have some support html -- but that's not the OP question.  There is PocketLearn commercial J2ME HTML component.  And I just found LWUIT 1.4, which sounds promising.

[LWUIT 1.4 release notes:](http://download.oracle.com/javame/dev-tools/lwuit-1.4/WhatsNewInThisRelease.html)

> The Lighweight UI Toolkit version 1.4 provides the following new or changed features:
>
> XHTML Support - LWUIT Now features the
>   ability to render XHTML-MP 1.0 content
>   and partial support for WCSS. LWUIT
>   Browser demo application - new demo
>   application showing the usage of the
>   HTML component.

Answer (score 1):

You can [use j2mehtml for displaying html content in J2ME](http://www.j2mehtml.com/).