# how can i open a browser within a midlet to display an HTML webpg?

Tags: java, html, bluetooth, midlet

I'm doing a project on Bluetooth n java. My server program gets the HTML source code of a web page n sends it to the client via BT. The client has to display the corresponding web page in a browser(that displays the webpage n not the HTML code). The browser should be opened within the MIDlet. Basically, i need a code for a Browser Screen, which is an HTML Parser.

Plzzz help.

Alternative options are to include the code to open the native browser for this or to use PicoBrowser or somethin like that. But i dont know how to implement all these. Someone please help.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried?

Comment: thanks. well, it was hard for me to write my own HTML parser. I tried using LWUIT, but, since i don't have much knowledge about it couldn't proceed further. I have been creating a MIDlet that displays a form to enter the URL with submit(passes the URL to ClientServer along with an instance of this MIDlet) n exit commands. I have to display the browserscreen in an openbrowser() method. This method is invoked by the ClientServer pgm after it retrieves the web page(HTML src code) sent by the Server(via BT). Now back to ma post. How to implement HTML Parser??!!

Answer (score 0):

HTML parsers & renderers for MIDP aren't common. You can try to find one, write your own, or rethink your requirements.

Related links:

- [How to display HTML content in J2ME?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618093/how-to-display-html-content-in-j2me)
- http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php/72540-How-to-display-HTML-from-within-my-J2ME-MIDP-MIDlet

Comment: yes, i'm aware of the options. i just need help implementing it. thank u for those threads. but i know all that. i just need to get an idea on things like how to include PicoBrowser in my midlet or should i send it to the client as a separate jar? also, i read that opening native browser exits the midlet. i donno if that would be a pblm. getInstance() wasn't recognized by my pgm anyways. n i need some big help to write my own parser!!